# Prepend multiple BuildTypes with the same steps in TeamCity Kotlin DSL

Tags: kotlin, teamcity

Let's say I have multiple Build Types in a project:

```
object Project : Project ({
    // ....
    buildType(foo)
    buildType(bar)
    buildType(baz)
})

object foo() : BuildType ({
    // ....
    steps {
        script {
            scriptContent = "echo foo"
        }
    }
})
```

foo, bar and baz buildTypes are too different inside and can't be converted to the single class.

Now I have a requirement to prepend steps section with two additional steps without modifying foo, bar or baz source code:

```
script {
    scriptContent = "echo step 1"
}
script {
    scriptContent = "echo step 2"
}
```

So, when I'll start build foo, it will output:

```
step 1
step 2
foo
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Successfully achieved it this way:

```
object Project : Project ({
    // ....
    buildType(commonSteps(foo))
    buildType(commonSteps(bar))
    buildType(commonSteps(baz))
})

fun commonSteps(buildType: BuildType): BuildType {
    val newSteps = arrayListOf(scriptStep("echo 123"), scriptStep("echo 321"))
    buildType.steps.items.addAll(0, newSteps)
    return buildType
}

fun scriptStep(scriptContent: String): ScriptBuildStep {
    val step = ScriptBuildStep()
    step.scriptContent = scriptContent
    return step
}
```

Comment: This provided useful insight for my project setup - although I did not use the function approach - I had build-configurations (per environment) defined in separate *.kt files and then referenced them from my Project.kt project file. This is the approach followed in [this tutorial here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2016/11/kotlin-configuration-scripts-an-introduction/).